# Parse String to DateTime on Windows Phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, datetime-format

I want to parse a string of this format "4/14/2013 ‎1:04 PM" to a DateTime object. But actually this doesn't work, because I'm getting an error of type 'System.FormatException'. How can I fix the problem and convert my DateTime string to a DateTime object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This works too!

```
var inputdt = "4/14/2013 1:04 PM";
var dt = DateTime.Parse(inputdt, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 4):

You input string is in en-us format, so you should specify correct `CultureInfo` format provider into `DateTime.Parse` method:

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("en-us");

var inputString = "4/14/2013 1:04 PM";
var dt = DateTime.Parse(inputString, ci);
```